# tracking zeros in bokeh plot with slider widget

Tags: python, widget, bokeh

I am creating an interactive plot that will track the zeros of the equation and the slider is adjusted. I am running into an issue on updating the zeros source data.

1) How to update/recalculate the zeros?

2) Is there a more efficient was to do this?

```
#@title Interactive Phase Plane Plot
output_notebook()
mu = 0
x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 2000)
y = mu*np.sin(x)-np.sin(2*x)
```

The original function before slider manipulation. The next section roughly estimates zeros.

```
def init_fp(x):
    fp_x = []
    fp_y = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(x):
        if np.abs(y[i]) > 0.005:
            pass
        else:
            fp_x.append(x[i])
            fp_y.append(0)
        i += 1
    return fp_x, fp_y
```

This section creates the data source for calback manipulation in the Bokeh plot.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'x' : x,
    'y' : y
})

fpx, fpy = init_fp(x)
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'fpx' : fpx,
    'fpy' : fpy
})
```

This defines the callback operation and inside is where I am updating the plot with the new func and recalculating the zeros.

```
callback_single = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, source1=source1), code="""
        var data = source.data;
        var mu = cb_obj.value
        var x = data['x']
        var y = data['y']
        var x1 = data['xfp']
        var y1 = data['yfp']
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            y[i] = mu*Math.sin(x[i])-Math.sin(2*x[i]);
        }
        source.change.emit();
        for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++){
            if (Math.fps(y[i]) < 0.05){
                x1[i] = x[i];
                y1[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        source1.change.emit();
    """)
```

Here is where the slider is defined and the plots are made, along with various 
aesthetics for the plot.

```
mu = Slider(start=-5, end=5, value=0, step=0.01, title="mu", callback=callback_single)
p = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=500)
p.line('x', 'y', source=source)
p.circle('fpx', 'fpy', source=source1)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color=None
p.ygrid.grid_line_alpha=0.8
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Theta'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'd Theta/dt'

t = Title()
t.text = 'Interactive Phase Plane Plot'
layout = column(p, widgetbox(mu))
p.title = t
show(layout)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that can be changed in your example:

- The `fpx`, `fpy` properties belong to `source1`, not to `source`.
- `Math.fps` should be `Math.abs`.
- You have a typo in the field names when retrieving `x1` and `y1`.
- The second loop in `CustomJS` callback wouldn't quite work if the number of zeros changes.

One way to rewrite the callback is as follows:

```
callback_single = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, source1=source1), code="""
        const mu = cb_obj.value
        const { x } = source.data;
        const y = x.map( val => mu * Math.sin(val) - Math.sin(2*val));
        source.data = { x, y };
        const fpx = x.filter((val, ind) => Math.abs(y[ind]) < 0.05);
        const fpy = fpx.map(() => 0);         
        source1.data = { fpx, fpy };
    """)
```

Also, there is a way to use more idiomatic numpy in `init_fp`:

```
def init_fp(x, y):
    fp_x = x[np.abs(y) < 0.05]
    fp_y = np.zeros_like(fp_x)
    return fp_x, fp_y
```

Here is the complete code, I left the math of zeros as is and also changed from `output_notebook` to `output_file`:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Slider, Title
from bokeh.plotting import figure
import numpy as np
output_file('zeros.html')
mu = 0
x = np.linspace(-2*np.pi, 2*np.pi, 2000)
y = mu*np.sin(x)-np.sin(2*x)

def init_fp(x, y):
    fp_x = x[np.abs(y) < 0.05]
    fp_y = np.zeros_like(fp_x)
    return fp_x, fp_y

source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'x' : x,
    'y' : y
})

fpx, fpy = init_fp(x, y)
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'fpx' : fpx,
    'fpy' : fpy
})

callback_single = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, source1=source1), code="""
        const mu = cb_obj.value;
        const { x } = source.data;
        const y = x.map( val => mu * Math.sin(val) - Math.sin(2*val));
        source.data = { x, y };
        const fpx = x.filter((val, ind) => Math.abs(y[ind]) < 0.05);
        const fpy = fpx.map(() => 0);
        source1.data = { fpx, fpy };
                               """)
mu = Slider(start=-5, end=5, value=0, step=0.01, title="mu", callback=callback_single)
p = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=500)
p.line('x', 'y', source=source)
p.circle('fpx', 'fpy', source=source1)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color=None
p.ygrid.grid_line_alpha=0.8
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Theta'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'd Theta/dt'

t = Title()
t.text = 'Interactive Phase Plane Plot'
layout = column(p, widgetbox(mu))
p.title = t
show(layout)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for your response. This was very informative!